# Erro quando executa comando grunt

Tags: javascript, grunt

então pessoal instalei o grunt aqui e quando executo o comando grunt aparece esse

erro no unglify targets found

> warning: task "unglify" failed. use --force to continue

meu gruntfile.js esta assim

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);
};
```

e o package.json assim

```js
{
  "name": "portifolio2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "versao final portifolio",
  "main": "bootstrap.min.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/fernandoRj/portifolio2.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/fernandoRj/portifolio2/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/fernandoRj/portifolio2#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

entao galera obrigado a quem respondeu o erro estava aqui

```js
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);
```

troquei por isso

```js
grunt.registerTask('default',[]);
```

Comment: Quais são os ficheiros que queres comprimir?

Comment: obrigado por tentar ajudar, resolvi o erro da maneira que eu editei o post

Comment: Fernando, duas coisas: `#1` a tua solução foi esconder o problema, ou seja sem o uglify ele não comprime os ficheiros. Nesse caso pergunto-me se vale a pena ter o Grunt, visto que ele não corre nenhuma task. `#2` quando encontrares uma solução coloca como resposta, no campo das respostas em baixo, e não mudando a pergunta em pergunta com resposta incluída.